# xcache count vs cpu count vs webadmin slots

Tags: xcache

Using xcache 3.1.0 on php 5.4.24 on a dual hexacore machine (12 cores):

```
[~]# cat /proc/cpuinfo |grep -c processor
12
```

I have entered 12 in the count property of the xcache object in the php.ini and the webadmin agrees:

[image]

However, I am getting 16 slots for php caching, all of which are being used:

[image]

Can anyone explain this?   Is this supposed to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick explanation to this situation might be that xcache is rounding 12 number to 16.

Reading your post, I also changed the xcache.count for my installation from 4 to 12, when I tested it, I got 16 threads instead of 12. I set it to 6, it rounded to 8 so I'm pretty sure xcache.count needs to be set to the power of 2.